# Flutter: Continuation of the future

Tags: flutter

I go from page 1 to page 2. The counting process starts on page 2. As this continues, I return to page 1. Even if I exit page 2, the process continues. Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?

Future.delayed keeps working when I return to page 1 from page 2.

This is page 1. There is only one button to go to page 2.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/page2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(

                backgroundColor: Colors.black38,

              ),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));

              },
              child: Text(
                'Page 2',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is page 2.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: MyHomePage2(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage2 extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _MyHomePage2State createState() => _MyHomePage2State();
}

class _MyHomePage2State extends State<MyHomePage2> {

  int d=0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    for (int c = 0; c < 25; c++) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: c), () {
        setState(() {
          d++;
        });
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            Text(
              ' $d',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your second page will still be alive even if you move to page 1. You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!mounted){
          return;
}
```

It happened thanks to the above. If I write one, it will probably suffice. I don't know if this is a valid solution.

```
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

      for (int c = kk; c < 25; c++) {
        if(!mounted){
          return;
        }
        
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: c), () {
            if(!mounted){
              return;
            }
            setState(() {
              d++;
            });
          });
          if(!mounted){
            return;
          }
      }

    super.initState();
  }
```